Transforming a matrix from cartesian coordinate to polar coordinate
I am trying to find the form of a matrix in cylinderical coordinates in Mathematica. The matrix in cartesian coordinates reads
$\begin{align}
    &u_r= u^*_r (r,\theta,t)+(L-z) (\boldsymbol{\nabla} L_{t})_{r},\\
       &u_{\theta}= u^*_{\theta} (r,\theta,t)+ (L-z) (\boldsymbol{\nabla} L_{t})_{\theta},\\
      &T^{xx}= 4 \mu h (L_{x} L_{xt}+u_{x})+2 \mu h (L_y L_{yt}+v_{y}),\\
    &T^{xy}= \mu h (u_{y}+v_{x}+ L_{x} L_{yt}+L_{y} L_{xt}),\\
    &T^{yy}= 4 \mu h (L_{y} L_{yt}+v_{y})+2 \mu h (L_x L_{xt}+u_{x}),\\
     &\boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \textbf{T}=0,\\
\end{align}$
The subscripts are the derivative with respect to x, y or t. The complication comes from the fact that I have many x and y derivatives on the variables and so do not know how to use Mathematica to write these in cylindrical coordinates. Here is the simple script I wrote to convert the matrix to a polar coordinate.
  Txx[x, y] := 4  h  \[Mu]  (
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ht\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(H\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y]) + 2 h  \[Mu]  (
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ht\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(H\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(v\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y]);
Txy[x, y] := h  \[Mu] (
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(v\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ht\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(H\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ht\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(H\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y]);
Tyy[x, y] := 4  h  \[Mu]  (
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ht\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(H\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(v\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y]) + 2 h  \[Mu]  (
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ht\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(H\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y]);
TC[x_, y_] = \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "", GridBox[{
{
RowBox[{"Txx", "[", 
RowBox[{"x", ",", "y"}], "]"}], 
RowBox[{"Txy", "[", 
RowBox[{"x", ",", "y"}], "]"}]},
{
RowBox[{"Txy", "[", 
RowBox[{"x", ",", "y"}], "]"}], 
RowBox[{"Tyy", "[", 
RowBox[{"x", ",", "y"}], "]"}]}
},
GridBoxAlignment->{"Columns" -> {{Center}}, "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}},
GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {
Offset[0.27999999999999997`], {
Offset[0.7]}, 
Offset[0.27999999999999997`]}, "Rows" -> {
Offset[0.2], {
Offset[0.4]}, 
Offset[0.2]}}], "", ")"}],
Function[BoxForm`e$, 
MatrixForm[BoxForm`e$]]]\);
MatrixForm[
 FullSimplify[
  TransformedField[
    "Cartesian" -> 
     "Polar", {{Txx[x, y], Txy[x, y]}, {Txy[x, y], Tyy[x, y]}}, {x, 
      y} -> {r, \[Theta]}] // Simplify]]

Then I tried to take the divergence of the matrix in polar coordinates, but I got an error
  div = Div[TC[r, \[Theta]], {r, \[Theta]}, "Polar"] // Simplify //
   Normal


You declared "TC" to be a function of 2 argument. However, in "Div" you use "TC" as a function of 3 arguments.

@DanielHuber Thanks for pointing this out. However, the issue is something else:

@DanielHuber I don't know how to use Mathematica to convert the derivatives in x ,y to polar coordinate derivatives (r,\theta). this is the main question

I think it's more complex than that as there are velocity components (vector components) in the equations too. @DanielHuber

With the corrected formula for Tc I get the following result:

Could it be that the problem is related to a version of MMA? I am using version 14.0.
